# Trouble using Shopify JAVA API

Tags: jakarta-ee, shopify, java

I am new to the Shopify Developer community and am trying to use the Shopify Java Adapter.
I am facing a difficulty using the Shopify JAVA api.

I downloaded the Java Adapter code from the following url:
https://github.com/shopify/shopify4j. 
It has some Android based classes but I am trying to use this for only a Java EE Environment.

I created the Credential Object as follows:

```
Credential c = new Credential(apiKey, secret, shopName);
APIAuthorization api = new APIAuthorization(c);
HttpClient client = api.getAuthorizedClient();
HttpResponse res = client.execute(new HttpGet(api.generateAuthRequest()));
```

However, it’s giving an empty response on executing this code.

I am really stuck with this issue. 
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: What version of HTTPClient are you using? You should probably use whatever one Android uses.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. i am using httpclient-4.0.jar File for HTTPClient class. 
if possible can you please send me an example code for how to use with Java only not for android.

Comment: Hi the java API is working fine but i am facing an issue when i send the request Params to any Service. can you please tell me the correct way to send the params to the Request.
Example
    OrdersService service = client.constructService(OrdersService.class);
    service.getOrders("fields=id");

when i run the above code it's giving me the following error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1140)
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:291)
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:211)

Comment: You should put that code in your question. I really cannot read it the way you just pasted it into the question comments section.

Comment: There's a few things that could've happened here.  1) There is a possibility something has changed in the API so the requests aren't working anymore. 2) We no longer use the old API token mechanism, only oAuth. 3) This code is old and unmaintained, so you are going to most likely need to go in and fix some stuff.

Comment: @NagaSrinuKapusetti do you know how to solve this issue. I'm facing same issue in my code

Comment: @Luffy we have created a java client for the same. you can check this. https://github.com/ankurnandu-canvass/canvass-ecom

Comment: @NagaSrinuKapusetti I tried to follow the given example but I'm still facing issues in using it. can you help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888256/capture-shopify-payment-response